# How to create Random number with 5 digit combined of number and charter

Tags: java, android, random

**I want to generate the random number like that**

- ADF1845CFT
- ADF1864ATY
- ADF18AT65Y

> **Note: There I FIX the ADF18** I want only take the next 5 digit with number and charter

I am successfully create the 5 digit with number

There is Various solution I am using

- [How to make combined random number matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608938/how-to-make-combined-random-number-matrix)
- [Java random number with given length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392693/java-random-number-with-given-length)

etc. method

With these method I am create successful random 5 digit numbers.

Any Help Appreciate....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use random UUIDs...

## Example:

```
final String randomCode = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
// or you can play with the len...
final String randomCode2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache commons-lang [`RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumberic`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphanumeric(int)):

```
"ADF18" + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumberic(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   String random5Digts = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5);
   String randomNumber="ADF18"+random5Digts;
   //code to change lower letters to uppercase
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(randomNumber);
   for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
       char c = sb.charAt(index);
       if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
           sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
       }
   }
   System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyStringRandomGen {

private static final String CHAR_LIST =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
private static final int RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH = 5;// change the number as u want.

/**
 * This method generates random string
 * @return
 */
public String generateRandomString(){

    StringBuffer randStr = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH; i++){
        int number = getRandomNumber();
        char ch = CHAR_LIST.charAt(number);
        randStr.append(ch);
    }
    return randStr.toString();
}

/**
 * This method generates random numbers
 * @return int
 */
private int getRandomNumber() {
    int randomInt = 0;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(CHAR_LIST.length());
    if (randomInt - 1 == -1) {
        return randomInt;
    } else {
        return randomInt - 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    MyStringRandomGen msr = new MyStringRandomGen();
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
    System.out.println(msr.generateRandomString());
}
}
```